# Pandas -> DataFrame -> rank

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the DataFrame, where I am trying to add a new "rank" column to determine the price rating relative to the "name" and "country" columns by comparing prices (column 'price'). But with no success. I need the following result, screenshot below.
Help please, I will be grateful
[image]

Comment: please post sample data in a text format.

Comment: It seems that the expected rank is only based on the name. Isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df['rank'] = df.groupby('name')['price'].rank(ascending=False)
```